# VB.Net -- Group Textboxes together to deal with them as one

Tags: vb.net

I am coding in vb.net and have 3 groups each with seven text boxes. I need a way to specify which group I want to change the particular property of, all in one go, in order to make a large chunk of code smaller.

```
    If x = 1 Then
        'Group1'
        Textbox1_(x).visible = True
        Textbox2_(x).visible = False
        '...etc
    ElseIf x = 2 Then
        'Group2'
        Textbox1_(x).visible = True
        Textbox2_(x).visible = False
        '...etc
    ElseIf x = 3 Then
        'Group3'
        Textbox1_(x).visible = True
        Textbox2_(x).visible = False
        '...etc
    End If
```

But I want a single statement if possible to deal with each group.
Hope that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and have a look at the set of tools in the post editor which allows you to format code as code.

Comment: If they are "grouped" in container controls (Tabs, Panels, GroupBox) you could loop thru the Controls collection for that container.  Barring that, you could define some arrays to hold them and loop thru those.

Comment: you can find controls by their name `Controls("Textbox1_" & x).Visible = False`

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed thank!

Answer (score 1):

Put your TextBox controls into an array:

```
Dim boxes(6,2) As TextBox
boxes(0,0) = Textbox1_1
boxes(1,0) = Textbox2_1
boxes(3,0) = Textbox3_1
boxes(4,0) = Textbox4_1
'...
boxes(6,2) = Textbox6_2
```

The code needs to run once, after `InitializeComponent()` is called for the form.

Then you can do this:

```
Me.SuspendLayout()
boxes(0,x).Visible = True
For i As Integer = 1 To 6
    boxes(i,x).Visible = False
Next i
Me.ResumeLayout()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the tag property. For example,

```
' for Group 1
Textbox1.Tag = 1
Textbox2.Tag = 1
Textbox3.Tag = 1
' etc for all of group 1
'for Group 2
Textbox4.Tag = 2
Textbox5.Tag = 2
Textbox6.Tag = 2
' etc for all the rest,
```

And then to find them,

```
Dim con As Textbox
If con.Tag = 1 Then   
  con.Visible = True
End If
If con.Tag = 2
  con.Visible = True
End If
```

It looks like if you use separate `If Statements` rather than `ElseIf` it makes it only make one group visible. Don't use a `For Each con In Me.Controls` because that will make all groups visible or invisible at once.

Comment: Seriously I just realized why one of my projects would not work. It was because I used the `For Each` as I said and it applied to everything. Glad I answered your question and saw my mistake.

Comment: Now you just need to adapt some of that code to fit it into your `If x =... ` part.